# How to reshape "#" and "." separated values in Python

Tags: python

I have a column which can take values in the below format, `S2_PN.some_value`. The N is fixed per column i.e. in this particular case the max value is 10 and for all the rows under this column there will be S2_P1 to S2_P10, but it can be in any order. S2_P10 can be first or the last or in the middle.

What i want is to split this into N columns and these columns should be populated with values that follows the "." after S2_PN. That is data in each row will be split into 10 columns and the value in the rows will be the string/number after the ".".

So the very first row will be split into 10 columns and column S2_P7 will be filled with 2, S2_P2 will be filled with "default".

The method that i have come up with seems tedious and inefficient. What i have done is first split this column in excel using the "Text to columns" separated by "#". There will be 10 columns. I then find for each resulting column using `Index and Match` the value corresponding to that position. So in short there are 100 columns with values and then by replacing the string "default" with "-1" and summing all the Sn_PN (for n in 1 to max(N)) i am reducing the 100 to 10 columns.

I am a beginner in Python and currently while i can split them into columns, after that is beyond my current skill set. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
#S2_P7.2#S2_P2.default#S2_P1.2#S2_P10.0#S2_P5.2#S2_P4.default#S2_P3.default#S2_P9.default#S2_P6.default#S2_P8.default
#S2_P10.0#S2_P9.default#S2_P4.default#S2_P1.0#S2_P5.0#S2_P2.default#S2_P6.default#S2_P7.0#S2_P8.default#S2_P3.default
#S2_P1.3#S2_P4.default#S2_P5.3#S2_P8.default#S2_P2.default#S2_P6.default#S2_P10.0#S2_P9.default#S2_P7.3#S2_P3.default
#S2_P10.0#S2_P9.0#S2_P8.2#S2_P3.2#S2_P2.2#S2_P6.2#S2_P1.2#S2_P5.2#S2_P4.2#S2_P7.2
#S2_P1.1#S2_P4.default#S2_P5.1#S2_P10.0#S2_P3.default#S2_P6.default#S2_P2.default#S2_P9.default#S2_P8.default#S2_P7.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show a solution for one row, `s`; you can hopefully put it in a loop and apply to all rows in your dataset.

First, use regular expressions to extract the columns:

```
regex = r"#S2_P([0-9]+)\.([^#]+)"
pieces = [(int(col), val) for col, val in re.findall(regex, s)]
#[(7, '2'), (2, 'default'), (1, '2'), (10, '0'), (5, '2'), (4, 'default'), 
# (3, 'default'), (9, 'default'), (6, 'default'), (8, 'default')]
```

Now, put the pieces in order and extract the values, because the column names are now implicit:

```
_, values = zip(*sorted(pieces))
print(values)
#('2', 'default', 'default', 'default', '2', 'default', 
# '2', 'default', 'default', '0')
```

This is the first line of your future table.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error `NameError: name 're' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks, i figured that out after i posted the comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `list` (or generator) of `dict` and pass it to `pandas`, e.g.:

```
In []:
import pandas as pd
with open('<file>') as f
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x.split('.') for x in line.strip().split('#') if x) for line in f)
df

Out[]:
  S2_P1 S2_P10    S2_P2    S2_P3    S2_P4 S2_P5    S2_P6 S2_P7    S2_P8    S2_P9  
0     2      0  default  default  default     2  default     2  default  default   
1     0      0  default  default  default     0  default     0  default  default
2     3      0  default  default  default     3  default     3  default  default
3     2      0        2        2        2     2        2     2        2        0
4     1      0  default  default  default     1  default     1  default  default
```

Comment: While this works it gives no insight to the OP on how/why. He said he is a beginner so nested comprehensions is probably going way over his head

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I tried running your code on a csv but am getting this error:

`df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x.split('.') for x in line.strip().split('#') if x) for line in csv_f)`

`AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: How are you converting the data to numpy? My assumption had been you are reading this in as plain strings.

Comment: I am not converting the data. The text is present in a csv file. I used pandas to read the csv and then applied your logic. `csv_f = pd.read("book1.csv",header=none)` thats all and then your code.

Comment: Just replace `'<file>'` with `'book1.csv'` in the code above, it's not really in `csv` format so using `pandas` to `read_csv` doesn't make much sense.